# jquery empty() parallel with ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, delegates, parallel-processing

I have a jQuery-based page which replaces a lot of the content from the server.
There are a couple of things that are slow in this; the AJAX call to load the new content and the `.empty()` calls to remove and unbind previous content.

Currently the script does an AJAX call to the server and, upon success, removes old content and builds new content.

Since the script is basically doing nothing while waiting for the AJAX call to finish, couldn't I use this time to do the slow `.empty()` calls?

I was thinking of something like the following:

1. Start the AJAX call.
2. Run all the `.empty()` calls.
3. When both 1 and 2 are completed, build new content.

Steps 1 and 2 are easy, I understand step 3 would require delegates, which I'm not familiair with. How should I do this (assuming it's possible)?

Comment: `.empty` is synchronous, if you start it immediately after `$.ajax` (which is asynchronous), you can be 100% sure it will be done before the success callback is executed. `$.ajax(...); $(selector).empty();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin B is correct for most cases, however, there may be some theoretical scenarios where that might not work.  For example, if you were on a corporate LAN connection with fiber internet within reasonable distance to the networking equipment, and if you had a large chunk of html to remove from the DOM using the .empty() command, the response from the server might be returned before the command has finished executing.

Although, that will probably never be the case, I would suggest that you look into using jQuery's $.deferred() commands (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or using webworkers to concurrently run multi-threaded tasks ( see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-introduction-jsconcurrency for more info).

Comment: Deferred was pretty easy; `var deferred = $.ajax(...); $(...).empty(); deferred.done(function(json){...});`. Seems to work fine and improves responsiveness.

Comment: Using `.empty()` like this removes all DOM elements too, which may look badly. Instead, you could use the undocumented `$.cleanData($(...))` and do a `.empty()` (or just replace content with `.html()`) after the ajax loading. `$.cleanData()` does most of the work but leaves the DOM nodes intact, making the subsequent `.empty()` call a lot faster. Note that `$.cleanData()` does cleanly destroy jQueryUI widgets, so any changes that widgets make to the DOM may be reverted.